# Can I reset the default Toy Box?

Tags: xbox-one, disney-infinity-2.0

It seems I've accidentally deleted the default "Introduction to Toy Box" world. Is there a way to restore it? I expect a deletion & re-install of the game (or at least deletion of save data) would probably fix it, but I'd rather not lose the other data (mission progress in Play Sets & Toy Box Games, etc.) that would likely be destroyed in such a process.

Comment: Did you find a way?  I haven't deleted mine entirely, but glitches have removed various parts of the floor and it would be nice to reset rather than rebuild...

Comment: @Margaret I did. I'll try to remember to load it up and post a walkthrough this weekend - it's been awhile since I've played.

Answer (score 3):

Main Menu > Options > Game Options > Reset Introduction to the Toy Box

All toys will be kept, just resets the world

Comment: Good info. Welcome to Arqade, James! :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to restore a deleted world on Disney infinity 2.0 unless you were playing it on another HDD

Comment: That certainly applies to custom worlds, or customizations of the default Toy Box. However, this isn't about that - this is asking how to reset the default Toy Box to the same state as when you started the game. And it turns out that *is* possible. I just haven't gotten around to posting the self-answer.